# WPF DataGrid: Reordering Rows?

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, drag-and-drop, wpfdatagrid

I am creating a WPF data grid, and I want to be able to reorder rows by dragging and dropping, like this: I click on a row and drag it up or down. As I do, a marker shows where the row will be dropped if I release the mouse. When I do release the mouse, the dragged row is inserted where indicated by the marker.

Has anyone seen any articles or blog posts that show how to do this? I don't want to re-invent the wheel if I don't have to, and Google isn't turning up anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry--bad key word choice. Early morning, no coffee...

Turns out there are a number of samples, under "WPF DataGrid Drag and Drop". Here are <strike>three</strike> two:

[Vincent Sibal's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/27/more-datagrid-samples-custom-sorting-drag-and-drop-of-rows-column-selection-and-single-click-editing.aspx)
[Philipp Sumi's Blog](http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/03/moving-data-grid-rows-using-drag-and-drop)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using the drag and drop behavior called [GongSolutions.WPF.DragDrop](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop). It works on any `ItemsControl` and thus also on `DataGrid` It allows MVVM style use cases using attached property setters to enable it. You should check out the link for a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution: [Movable rows in WPF DataGrid](https://www.eidias.com/blog/2014/8/15/movable-rows-in-wpf-datagrid) best working for me. It's clean, MvvM pattern compatible. Has good example available to download.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).